# Find open and closed triads in a large Graph using Networkx

Tags: graph, networkx

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to find all the open and closed triads for a set of large Network Graph objects. Just to give an idea, the one I'm working on right now is 178593 nodes and 268831.

Now in order to find open and closed triads, i wrote the following function

```
def find_tri(G):

closed_T=[]
open_T=[]
for i in G.nodes():
    a = tuple([i] + G.neighbors(i)) #list concat
    if len(a) == 3:
        if len(G.subgraph([i] + G.neighbors(i)).edges()) == 3:
            if tuple(sorted(a)) not in closed_T: 
                closed_T.append(tuple(sorted(a)))
        else:
            sorted_triad=sorted(nx.degree(G.subgraph([i] + G.neighbors(i))), key=nx.degree(G.subgraph([i] + G.neighbors(i))).get)
            open_T.append(tuple(sorted_triad))
    elif len(a) > 3:
        #triad_neig=  filter(lambda t: i in t, list(itertools.combinations(G.subgraph([i] + G.neighbors(i)).nodes(),3)))
        triad_neig=list(itertools.combinations(G.subgraph([i] + G.neighbors(i)).nodes(),3))
        triad_neig = [x for x in triad_neig if i in x]            
        for k in triad_neig:

            if len(G.subgraph(k).edges()) == 3:
                if tuple(sorted(k)) not in closed_T:
                    closed_T.append(k)

            elif len(G.subgraph(k).edges()) == 2:
                if k not in open_T:
                    sorted_triad=sorted(nx.degree(G.subgraph(k)), key=nx.degree(G.subgraph(k)).get)
                    open_T.append(tuple(sorted_triad))

return open_T, closed_T
```

The function is then applied to an nx.Graph(), and it works pretty well for small graphs. But for the one that I described above, is currently running for more than 15 hours. I think I need to improve the efficiency of the function, but i really don't know what to change. 
Anyone has some suggestion? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm reading the code and I'm struggling to follow what it's doing.  Your first `if` statement seems to be testing whether `i` has two neighbors and if so, whether they have an edge between them.  But it does this by first creating a tuple, checking to see if the tuple has 3 nodes, then it checks to see whether the subgraph induced on those 3 nodes has 3 edges?  That seems much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: A step that is really going to slow you down is checking whether a tuple is in a list.  This will take a huge number of steps since it has to compare it to each and every one of the existing tuples until it finds a match or determines there is none.  At the very least, use a set.  Then you can add the tuple to the set without worrying about whether it's already there or not.

Comment: The code in your 'elif' block looks even more involved.  Why not just look at all pairs of neighbors and determine whether they have an edge between them or not?

Comment: It's not at all clear why you have to separate the 2 neighbor and more than 2 neighbor cases.